# Rails create association before triggering after_create causing order to throw exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the snippet below in an `after_create` callback on a model that's irrelevant to the problem.  This is the code in the callback:

```
a = Appointment.new

a.carrier = self.pro.carrier
a.name = 'Pending'
a.status = 'Entered'

au = AppointmentUser.new
au.user_id = 1000

a.appointment_users << au 

a.save
```

`au.appointment_id` should be set when the `Appointment` is created.

The `Appointment` model (what I'm creating) has an `after_create` callback on it that uses the association created in the snippet above (`AppointmentUser`).

However, Rails is creating the `Appointment` object prior to creating the `AppointmentUser`, thus causing an error to be thrown inside of the callback on the `Appointment` model because the callback needs to use the association which has not yet been created.

How can I write this code differently to avoid this problem, or how can I change my callback to prevent this from happening?

Edit:

Attempt using answer below:

```
puts au.to_json
puts 'this is au, before assoc'

appointment.appointment_users << au 

puts au.to_json
puts 'this is au, after assoc'
```

Output from the above:

```
{"deleted_at":null,"id":24748,"appointment_id":null,"user_id":1555,"created_at":"2015-08-26T08:59:19.219-07:00","updated_at":"2015-08-26T08:59:19.219-07:00","assigns":null}
    this is au, before assoc
    {"deleted_at":null,"id":24748,"appointment_id":null,"user_id":1555,"created_at":"2015-08-26T08:59:19.219-07:00","updated_at":"2015-08-26T08:59:19.219-07:00","assigns":null}
```

Comment: because of your call `a.save`

Comment: So what do you propose I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/mqpqejsktti7eyssz5mkqq

Comment: Uhm... This is the same code in my OP..

Comment: read the comments I gave in the link.. it is not same :)

Comment: Check comments in answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 ...
 au.save
 a.appointment_users << au
 a.save
 ...
```

Comment: a.appointment_users << au isn't setting the appointment_id.  Why would that be?

Comment: because your `a` object is not created yet, while you are trying to set it with `<<`

Comment: Mmm so is this possible?

Comment: you have to create `a` before adding it to `au`

Comment: But then the callback runs.  Like a catch 22.  What should I do?

Comment: The callback runs after creation.  In the callback it must reference the au.  What are my alternatives?